# VB.NET - Net Use * /Delete without shell?

Tags: vb.net, unc

I am creating a quick sync software that connects to a UNC network path with credentials.

I need to try not to use shell if I can avoid it.

The code to make the connection is this:

```
Dim nr As New NETRESOURCE
nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK
nr.lpRemoteName = "\\fileserver.server.com\data"
If WNetAddConnection2(nr, "pas", "server.com\user", 0) <> NO_ERROR Then
    ' Throw New Exception("WNetAddConnection2 failed.")
End If
'Code to use connection here.'
If WNetCancelConnection2("\\fileserver.server.com\data", 0, True) <> NO_ERROR Then
    ' Throw New Exception("WNetCancelConnection2 failed.")
End If
```

Once the sync has completed, I need to terminate the connection the same way "Net Use * /delete" works. If possible to not disconnect any mapped network drives.

Is this simple to do in VB.NET?

**EDIT**... I think the code I am looking for is what I posted above.. my bad!

Comment: Pass 4 as the last argument to make the connection temporary.  That way the drive mapping won't be remembered, even if your program crashes or is terminated.

Comment: @MattWilko no, but I'm from Essex and I have mutual friends with the guy.